# hadoop mapreduce job fails as it checking for jars in the HDFS (only in hbase jobs)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Hadoop mapreduce job fails with the below exception if the job has hbase handling as in the below log, how ever I added the wanted jars to `hadoop_classPath`.
I can overcome this issue by adding the wanted jars on the wanted path on HDFS but I think that isn't the correct handling for the issue.

I want to know if there is missed thing that I should do to handle this issue.

BTW this issue is the same as in:

- [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032771/hbase-bulk-load-mapreduce-hfile-exception-netty-jar/22967706#22967706)
- [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536991/hbase-importtsv-filenotfoundexception/22968263#22968263)
- [issue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239964/hbase-looks-for-hadoop-common-library-on-hdfs)

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:     hdfs://localhost/dedge1/hadoop/hbase-0.96.1.1-hadoop2/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1110)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:264)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:300)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:387)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
```